# Creating MBtiles file from ".osm.pbf" file using TileMill

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, mapbox, tilemill, mapbox-studio

I am using Mapbox Offline Map in my app using MBTiles. Previously I was using shapefiles for creating offline maps. After searching a lot I am not getting Australian shapefiles.

But my friend referred this [URL](http://download.geofabrik.de/australia-oceania/australia.html) which contain all the layers of MBtiles of ".osm.pbf" format (not .shp format).

Is there any way to use ".osm.pbf" file in TileMill to create MBtiles file or a way to convert ".osm.pbf" file to ".shp" file and then use it in TileMill?

Answer (score 1):

Specifically answering the question you could use

**osm2pgsql** to get the open street map into postgres.

From here you can use postgres to shape command line

**pgsql2shp**

Bear in mind - TileMill is going to generate a rastered image map tile / not a vector. Using the original protocol buffer format / pbf is a better place to start and then you can apply styles on the fly.

Have a look at this video for high level overview of vector maps
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=se2cd3BMYRY

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`ogr2ogr`](https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to convert .osm.pbf to .shp file.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -skip  CGK.osm.shp CGK.osm.pbf
```