# From osm.pbf data to mbtiles (pbf vector tiles inside a sqlite3 container)?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox, vector-tiles, mbtiles, pbf

I need to experiment with vector tiles based on [OSM](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) data.

To do that, I've downloaded an OSM `*.osm.pbf` data file from [geofabrik.de](https://www.geofabrik.de/).

I want now to store these data either as the standard [`/tileset/{Z}/{X}/{Y}.vector.pbf`](https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/specification/) files, or as a single [sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html)-flavoured [`*.mbtiles`](https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/blob/master/1.3/spec.md) file (better).

Do you know a straightforward way to proceed using command line tool(s) on Linux (Ubuntu server 18.04), and, if possible, without passing through a [PostGIS](https://postgis.net) database?

A docker based solution could also be useful.

The tricky part will certainly be to set up a symbology (for which I don't know from where to explore at the time of writing...) but I wonder if one can use some predefined one such as the [cartodb positron](https://carto.com/blog/getting-to-know-positron-and-dark-matter/) for example, or online tools such as https://cloud.maptiler.com/customize/#streets/0.82/0/0 or https://maputnik.github.io/editor/#0.83/0/0 to generate a custom `style.json` file which could then be used somewhere in a config?

What I've tried so far:

I've thought writing data to a sqlite3 database as follows could be a nice idea, but this will obviously not make it 'mbtiles' ready (i.e. it will not be encoded as protobuf chunks):
`wget -O - http://www.example.com/some.pbf | ogr2ogr -f SQLite my.sqlite /vsistdin/`
(this latter command is explained [here](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html))

I also gave [GDAL's MVT driver](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mvt.html) a try, but this doesn't seem to work very well (I'm unable to serve the so build tiles, e.g. [tileserver-gl](http://tileserver.org/) complains that the tiles are not in the "openmaptiles" format (why?). And I cannot figure out if this format is implemented in GDAL. Maybe I need another server then?):
`ogr2ogr -f MVT mytileset my_osm_data.osm.pbf -o METADATA_FILE='./tileset/metadata.json'`

[Creating MBtiles file from ".osm.pbf" file using TileMill](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188484) is outdated for my usage.